# R source command in package

Tags: r, package

How can I source my function files in r-packages?

Example (tree dir of my package, package name is "pack"):

```
- man (help files)
- R
 -- pack.function1.R
 -- pack.function2.R
 -- ...
- myfunctions
 -- functions.R
DESCRIPTION
NAMESPACE
...


functions.R
foo <- function(bar) {
   return(bar)
}


pack.function1.R
...
source("myfunctions/functions.R")
foo(bar)
```

I tried "myfunctions/functions.R", "/myfunctions/functions.R", "../myfunctions/functions.R" but it does work.

How is the correct source path? It's my first try with R packages.

Comment: Put the whole path in, not just this derectory. Otherwise, set a new working derctory with `setwd`. You can also check what's your current working directory with `getwd()` and put your file there, and then your code will work

Comment: and what is if another user install the package on his machine?

Comment: One way is to check what's R default directory and make sure that your function will be always there. Or you can put it in some shared folder that everyone have access to. I don't have any other ideas, maybe some more experienced users can add some input

Comment: If you are making a package, you have to build and check it, then distribute it (maybe privately), and when your other users have the .tar.gz they can use `install.packages()` to install it.  The approach you are taking is not the standard approach, and your directory structure will not work.  See 'Writing R Extensions' on the R manual page to get the details you need.  It's worth the investment to learn how to do it.

Comment: No need to `source`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40642425/4468078

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to organize the R code files in your package into different (sub) folders.

This is not supported within R packages.

If you install your package you can query the installation path from a function within your package:

```
system.file(package = "data.table")
[1] "/home/ryoda/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/data.table"
```

But if you look into the R folder of the installed package you will not find your R code but a "precompiled" image of all your R code (see the *.rdb and *.rdx files).

Therefore you cannot source other R source code files within R.

For details around the folder structure see: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages

**PS: There is (at least) one "back-door":**

If you put R files of your package into a sub folder under the package root named `inst` the contents of the `inst` sub folder will be copied recursively to the installation directory and could be source then (use `system.file(package = getPackageName())` to retrieve the installation path from within your package.

But this is far beyond the way a package should work.

A valid exception could be: Provide pre-configured configuration files that are pure R files creating variables...